# ask password when cloning from gitlab docker by ssh

Tags: git, docker, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have run a gitlab docker container in linux box.
the configuration of docker-composer is as follows:

```
services:                                                                   
   image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'                                     
   container_name: gitlab                                               
   restart: always                                                      
   hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'                                      
   ports:                                                               
     - '192.168.0.22:80:80'                                              
     - '192.168.0.22:443:443'                                            
     - '192.168.0.22:2222:22'                                            
   volumes:                                                             
     - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'                                 
     - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'                               
     - '/opt/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'                               
   environment:                                                         
       - GITLAB_SSH_PORT = 2222
```

In MS Windows, I have tried to clone a repository from the docker container by ssh.
For this, I already generated ssh key by ssh-keygen in git bash shell

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my@email.com"
```

And registerd public key in gitlab web interface and tested ssh connection by the following command

```
ssh -vt git@192.168.0.22
```

the debug message says

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:5DpPwXu9nlXyzVXC8+H222hspaHRuSv9OXmFdAscIKM /d/home/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /d/home/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /d/home/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /d/home/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /d/home/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@192.168.0.22's password:
```

It looks like referring correct key (/d/home/.ssh/id_rsa) but asking password instead of publickey.

I have searched in stackoverflow and gitlab site about this behavior but none did solve this behavior.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Do you need a `-p 2222` in your ssh command?  (Are you actually connecting to the normal host sshd?)

Comment: @DavidMaze it's little bit confusing. As your comment, what I did with ssh is actually connecting to host's ssh instead of gitlab docker's ssh. so I should specify the right port  number for the gitlab docker. is it right?

Comment: Right; I’d guess the command you showed is connecting to the host and not the container.